# Laravel HREF techniques for multiple pages

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

```
<!-- BEGIN HEADER MENU -->
<div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown dropdown-fw dropdown-fw-disabled active open selected">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="text-uppercase"><i class="icon-home"></i> Home </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fw">
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url('picture/externalphotoviewer') }}"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> View Photo </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="{{ url('picture/about') }}"><i class="icon-bulb"></i> About </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url('picture/contact') }}"> <i class="icon-graph"></i> Contact </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown dropdown-fw dropdown-fw-disabled">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="text-uppercase"><i class="icon-home"></i> Upload </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fw">
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url('photo/create') }}"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> Upload Photo </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url('photo') }}"><i class="icon-bulb"></i> View Photo List </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am still new to this but basically, I have 5 pages (View Photo, About, Contact, Upload Photo, View Photo List). Currently, I want to show this HTML in all 5 pages so that it will be standardized. If I change the "picture/about" in one page to "photograph/about" for example, the 5 pages will need to reflect this change. This gets more complex as the number of pages increases.

Is there any way or technique in Laravel to solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a template file like Laravel provides `app.blade.php` in `resources/template/` directory, use `extends`, `sections` etc for designing, please read [Laravel Documentation for Templates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#defining-a-layout)

Comment: I read the part about templates and have used it in my project. However, using template would be impossible for me because each HEADER MENU is different. Each of them would have the different <li class="Active"> depending on what page I am on

Comment: I guess you'll have problem in showing menu `active` right

Answer (score 0):

You can use partials for this.

If your issue is adding the active class to the correct link then you can just use `request()->is()` to check the current url:

```
<li class="{{ request()->is('picture/externalphotoviewer') ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <a href="{{ url('picture/externalphotoviewer') }}">
        <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> View Photo </a>
</li>
<li class="{{ request()->is('picture/about') ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <a href="{{ url('picture/about') }}">
        <i class="icon-bulb"></i> About </a>
</li>
<li class="{{ request()->is('picture/contact') ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <a href="{{ url('picture/contact') }}">
        <i class="icon-graph"></i> Contact </a>
</li>
```

Simply create a blade file inside your `resources/views` directory and then use `@include` e.g.

**reasources/views/partials/header.blade.php**:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown dropdown-fw dropdown-fw-disabled active open selected">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="text-uppercase">
                <i class="icon-home"></i> Home </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fw">
                <li class="{{ request()->is('picture/externalphotoviewer') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                    <a href="{{ url('picture/externalphotoviewer') }}">
                        <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> View Photo </a>
                </li>
                <li class="{{ request()->is('picture/about') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                    <a href="{{ url('picture/about') }}">
                        <i class="icon-bulb"></i> About </a>
                </li>
                <li class="{{ request()->is('picture/contact') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                    <a href="{{ url('picture/contact') }}">
                        <i class="icon-graph"></i> Contact </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown dropdown-fw dropdown-fw-disabled">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="text-uppercase">
                <i class="icon-home"></i> Upload </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-fw">
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url('photo/create') }}">
                        <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i> Upload Photo </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ url('photo') }}">
                        <i class="icon-bulb"></i> View Photo List </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then replace the header code in your other blade files with:

```
@include('partials.header')
```

**NB**

If you change the location of the header you will need to update the `@include`'s as well e.g.

e.g. `resources/views/layouts/main/header.blade.php` would be `@include('layouts.main.header')`

Hope this helps!